# How to get workspace directory in bazelrc

Tags: bazel, address-sanitizer, bazelrc

I want to specify a ASAN suppression file in .bazelrc. And the suppression file is located in workspace directory. I tried as following:

```
build:debug --action_env=LSAN_OPTIONS=suppressions=${workspace}/asan_leaks.supp
```

and

```
build:debug --action_env=LSAN_OPTIONS=suppressions=%workspace%/asan_leaks.supp
```

But what I got is:

```
AddressSanitizer: failed to read suppressions file
'/projects/mytest/bazel-output/execroot/mytest/bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/mytest/${workspace}/asan_leaks.supp'
```

and

```
AddressSanitizer: failed to read suppressions file 
'/projects/mytest/bazel-output/execroot/mytest/bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/mytest/%workspace%/asan_leaks.supp'
```

It works if I hardcoded an absolute path, so I try to get the absolute path of workspace. Any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: I see some discussion happened on the same  [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3216)

Comment: Thanks @SG_Bazel for your information. That's exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just update my workaround in case that somebody encouter similar issue:

1. Hardcode the suppression file with absolute path as following:

   build:debug --action_env=suppressions=/tmp/asan_leaks.supp
2. Specify workspace_status_command relative to workspace directory

   build --workspace_status_command=./bazel/cmd.sh
3. Make soft link to the suppression file in cmd.sh

   bazel_dir=$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f $0;)")
   ln -sf ${bazel_dir}/asan_leaks.supp /tmp/asan_leaks.supp